# Inactive App Notification: How to configure if a sound should be played or not

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM in my app. The user can configure if notifications should be displayed within the app. I have implemented `GcmListenerService` to create a notification within `onMessageReceived`.

However, this only works as long as the app is active. As soon as the app is inactive, Android takes over and displays the notification. What is the recommended way to configure if notifications should be displayed or not when a `GCM` message is being sent?

Comment: By *inactive app*, do you mean that the app is in background?

Comment: Your problem seems to be similar with this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251876/how-to-enable-and-disable-gcm-in-android). Check it out.